# One word for visiting places shown in movies or tv series?

Tags: single-word-requests, cinema

Is there  a word for travelling to film locations where popular scenes were shot. Like Globetrotter for a person visiting different countries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably thinking of **set jetting**.

> the practice of visiting places used as locations in feature films
>
> collinsdictionary.com:set-jetting -
>   https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/set-jetting

...

> Set-jetting is the trend of traveling to destinations that are first seen in movies.[1] It is also referred to as a "Location Vacation". Touring London in a high-speed boat like James Bond, or visiting the stately homes that are seen in the Jane Austen films are good examples.
>
> The term was first coined in the US press in the New York Post by
>   journalist Gretchen Kelly in 2008.[2] An analysis about the use of
>   Geospatial technologies in setjetting was proposed by Thierry Joliveau
>   in The Cartographic Journal.[3]
>
> Corporations, convention and tourism boards are exploiting the trend,
>   creating their own set-jetting travel maps, like the Elizabeth: The
>   Golden Age movie map published by VisitBritain.[4][5]
>
> In June 2018, Maya Beach, made famous by Danny Boyle's 2000 film The
>   Beach, was closed indefinitely to allow it to recover from the
>   ecological damage of mass tourism.[6] The beach received up to 5,000
>   tourists and 200 boats a day.[6]
>
> Wikipedia:setjetting - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setjetting

...

> Set jetting or film tourism is defined as tourist
>   travel to a destination because of its appearance in a film (or
>   films). It is being driven by the globalisation of the entertainment
>   industry, has been attributed to raising the awareness of previously
>   unheard of tourist destinations, and regenerating waning interest in
>   others.
>
> https://www.onecaribbean.org/content/files/SetJetting.pdf

There are many travel agencies and tourism groups that cater to this niche.

Comment: Please don't answer questions which don't meet this site's community-determined quality standards.

Answer (score 1):

[Cine-tourism](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/fe76/34e42135b30e92c51f214d8ec851d5697417.pdf) is the term I'm seeing online lately.

It's been in articles discussing the bump in tourism from people seeing the locales in movies.

[Example](https://www.mumbrella.asia/2019/01/crazy-rich-asians-cine-tourism-will-it-bring-more-people-to-visit-singapore): *Crazy Rich Asians* Cine-Tourism, Will it Compel More People to Visit Singapore.

[Example](https://www.avenuemail.in/india/cine-tourism-boosts-economy/97373/): Cine-Tourism Boosts the Economy.

I'm also seeing the above mentioned film tourism.

Comment: Please don't answer questions which don't meet this site's community-determined quality standards.

Comment: @curiousdannii This question just barely meets the standards for a single word request. That's why it took over a week for it to close.  Other high level users looked at it and passed it over.  The OP has described what the word would mean "A globetrotter ..." You're punishing his ineloquent description.  Hence I answered, but did not upvote his question.   Vote to close questions as you wish, but don't scold others for answering. Opinions of validity vary.

Comment: There's no sample sentence. There's no explanation of what part of speech the OP wants. There's no suggested ways to evaluate answers.

Comment: @curiousdannii Hence, you voted to close.  I didn't start a reopen campaign. It's not the highest quality question. My objection is to you scolding the answerers.  It's unnecessary. Run for moderator if you want. Otherwise, make your statement with your close vote and that's that.

Answer (score 0):

It's a form of tourism, but Merriam-Webster has [no neologism for visiting film locations](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/film%20tourism). "Film tourism" would be a good choice.

Comment: Actually, I had seen a word earlier but I am not able to recollect it .